# How to make multiple regex replacements

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this string of my domain:

```
www.my.domain.com
```

and I want my output to be:

```
my.domain
```

I do it currently like this:

```
str.replace("www.","").replace(".com","")
```

How can I make it with only one replacement instead of two?

Comment: str.replace(/(www\.|\.com)/g, '')
Not the most elegant code, but should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
str.replace(/www\.|\.com/g, '');
```

If you're not familiar with the syntax `|`means "or", making it match the patterns on both sides. `\.`since period otherwise means "any character". `/g`makes the matching and replacing "global", i.e. processes all occurrences. If you want it to be case insensitive you can use `/gi` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what to do:-

`str.replace(/^www\.|\.com$/g, '');`

With beginning and end position search.

Will not go wrong with www.my.comedy-domain.com

Comment: Good point. Though that is not equivalent to his original replace, it is certainly better for this particular use.